# Flush Input Buffer C

Tags: c, math, buffer, flush, cstdio

Note: fflush(stdin) did not work.

**Problem:**
I'm entering numbers in as a while loop using scanf (inb4 depreciated). When I enter one, the buffer fills the rest in with blank lines.

**Code:**

```
double input, total;

for(i=0; i<COUNT; i++){
     printf("\nNumber %d: ", i+1);
     scanf("%d", &input);
     total += input;
}
printf("\nAverage: %f\n", total/COUNT);
```

**Output:**

```
Please enter 5 decimal numbers: 
Number 1: 1.0

Number 2: 
Number 3: 
Number 4: 
Number 5: 
Average: 0.000000
```

Comment: Why are you using `%d` to take a float value in scanf? Use `%f`.

Comment: and what happend when you enter "0" from 2 to 5?

Comment: do i not see ist or is the decleraction from COUNT missing?

Comment: As usual, you forgot to add "\n" to the scanf format (and it should be "%f" and not "%d"). Try using "%f\n" and you should see a better result.

Comment: scanf needs to be told when a newline occurs. "\n" allows to skip the end of line and be ready to read the next value. See any man page for detail, or do a search here on SO. The question has been answered like half a million times.

Comment: @kuroineko My bad. Assumed it was unnecessary here. You're right.

Comment: @FabianHarmsen it is defined at the top of the file. `#define COUNT (x number here)`

Comment: @kuroineko Need not `"\n"` adds if you type in succession number. It is ignored by default. Further, it should be `%lf` instead of `%d`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Except if the input does not match as a float. Anyway, this has been documented here on SO a million times or more...

Comment: @kuroineko now  `125,141`
questions tagged C. :-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sure, but if you count the OP's comments, you can bet it's somewhere between 1 and 10 millions ;)

Comment: @kuroineko see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404191/scanf-requires-more-inputs-than-requested Effect immediately.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(scanf("%d", &input) != 1)
 {
      /* If scanf failed to read a number clear the input buffer */
      while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flushall() before taking the input
Also you have used %d to store in double,use %lf, or declare input as int

Comment: `flushall` is non-standard.